Issue with docker-compose up with swagger spring boot
Docker compose issue with swagger-server
Hi all, I am facing an issue with an issue with swagger boot when you running $ docker-compose up.
I am using a centralized swagger for microservices it is working fine when running locally but when I am running the same application with docker-compose I need to re run my swagger-server service container manually after docker compose up.
the issue is that when I am running all my microservice with docker-compose I am unable hit any end point on port which is running swagger-server. When I am hitting any port I am getting
this page isn't working right now
local host didn't send any data
  swagger-server:
    image: tejajagadeep/movie-app-swagger-server:latest
    container_name: swagger-server
    environment:
      - eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
      - spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://config-server:8888/
    ports:
      - "8769:8769"
    networks:
      - my-movie-network
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - config-server
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8769/actuator/health"]
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10

but if re run my swagger-server image it is working fine. ( I am using open docs web mvc dependency in my spring boot swagger server]
here is my github issue link
source code for the above
How can I resolve this issue I don't think there is any issue with the code cause I have everything in the application property itself.

Can you add docker compose logs, when you run docker compose up for the first time? It will be easier to detect the problem. Or check that helthcheck woks correctly.

That is the there no logs I am just getting error page This page isn’t working right now. It is not even fetching data

When you run command "docker-compose up" without arg "-d" in terminal should be container's logs. Or your service don't have logs at all?
I expected that in logs we can find service initialize errors. Some configs or parameters.

These errors could happen because of services which swagger-server depends on were started but not ready to use.

Solution:
As mentioned in the comments the issue is with it is starting before dependent services so I am adding this command will not let it start until the config server starts and is healthy.
    entrypoint: sh -c "apk --no-cache add curl && /bin/sh -c 'until curl -sSf http://config-server:8888/actuator/health; do echo \"Waiting for config-server to be healthy...\"; sleep 5; done' && java -jar /usr/src/swagger-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"


I added this which solved the issue which also solved other service re running because of on-failure line.
